# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 502 Bad Gateway nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bootstrap-5, metronic

I got 2 proyects in Spring Boot 3.1.1, java 17 and bootstrap. One of them is working fine on Elastic Beanstalk (Corretto 17 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.9) but the same proyect with added *Metronic Templates and Styles from KeenThemes*, after deploy, shows Severe state and message 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. When I try on my URL, shows "502 Bad Gateway by nginx". Of course, both locally, works fines.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I normally use 3 application.propeties. The principal and one for DEV and one for PROD. I left just one. Ther is no much things to try because is the same proyect. I don't tkink it'a a load balancer problem. Not the navigator, no ports have been changed. Just works again when I deploy de last version with no Metronic templates.

Comment: Update: Folder _keenthemes is not inside /src folder. So I copy folder _keenthemes inside /resource/static folder. Now I got that folder in my .jar file but it can't find config.json file. I try with File file = new File("/resources/static/keenthemes/config/themesettings.json") but in localhost does no work. Not work /static/keenthemes/config/themesettings.json and no work /keenthemes/config/themesettings.json     Regards

Comment: SOLVED: I use Amazon S3 and retreive files from there.